# Only apply cell calculation if cell next to it was edited

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets

Instead of having a formula auto calculate through the whole column, I want the cell in a column only to apply the formula once the date was set in column A2. Its a count up feature. Right now the calculation takes the current time n C2 minus the time stamp in cell B2 that gives me a count up feature.

The formula that I am using "=C2-B2" which I want to apply to the whole column applies it automatically even tho there is no data in cell A2.

I want the count up only to start once they filled in the date in column A2 as this triggers my Script for time stamp. Right now its just got count ups on the whole column cells with the source cells arent even filled in .

Comment: You have an existing spreadsheet. Please share it, or a version of it.

Comment: You've included the "excel" tag - how is that relevant to your question.

Comment: As it might be relevant to the formula I am using even if in Google Sheets

Comment: _As it might be relevant to the formula I am using even if in Google Sheets_ Ahh. no. BTW, are you going to share your spreadsheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pjfm4iT5vSZtBRDoG2llspmbdKED6rllqN_aBeSFT40/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let me know if you able to open it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly...
Add the following directly after `e.source.getSheetByName('validated').getRange(row, 2).setValue(date);` in your onedit.

```
var countdownrange = e.source.getSheetByName('validated').getRange(row, 4);
countdownrange.setFormulaR1C1("=R[0]C[-1]-R[0]C[-2]");
var nowrange = e.source.getSheetByName('validated').getRange(row, 3);
nowrange.setFormula("=NOW()");
```

Comment: Worked, Thank you

Comment: If this answer was useful, please consider "accepting" it.